# Use find and a script to extract data in Linux terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, find

I am working on an assignment for my linux class and I am not sure what to do next. There is a directory `election2008` that holds data in spreadsheets from the 2008 election. In `election2008` there are six directories, `Apr`, `Aug`, `Feb`, `Jan`, `Jul`, `Jun`.  And inside those are spreadsheets for each day of the month in .csv files.

I created a script called `extractdata` that will take the data I need from the spreadsheets.  I don't need the first 2 lines or any of the lines after 53.  So I created the following script `extractdata`.

```
#!/bin/bash
head -n 53 $1 | tail -n 51
```

The next step is to use the `find` command and my `extractdata` script to get the data of all the .csv files in the month directories and then place the results in a file called `polls.csv`.  I am stuck on the command I need to execute to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside the election2008 directory:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" | xargs -n1 <path to extractdata script> >> polls.csv
```

So if extractdata is in the election2008 directory (and is executable) it would be:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" | xargs -n1 ./extractdata >> polls.csv
```

Since this command is appending to the polls.csv file you would need to delete that file each time you want to rerun this.